# args in '.bat' file contain some spaces, how could I get the args correctly?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

Stat command in cmd:

```
start.bat -arg1 -ar g2 -arg3
```

How can I get the second arg? The string 'ar g2' contain one space .

I need get the args(may contain space character) from bat file, then I will handle them in the java file.

Could anybody give me a solution? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

On the (DOS/Windows) command line, you should always surround arguments that contain spaces, with quotes. E.g.

```
start.bat -arg1 "-ar g2" -arg3
```

Surrounding each and every argument with quotes, even ones without spaces, will not hurt, but your batch script needs to remove the quotes then (see code samples below).

This has been the case for as long as I can remember (pre-Windows 3.1 DOS days). When long filenames (which could include spaces) were implemented, this became more common. E.g.

```
C:\Users\adam>copy "My Documents" "My Backup Files"
```

(try it without quotes too).

This is the CMD way, and any programs called from the CMD will understand this correctly.

Code Samples (may be useful for debugging, to see what actually is returned. Run the Batch file or Java class with a list of arguments and play around.)

**Batch script** (the **~** (tilde) character is the important thing, it removes the surrounding quotes):

```
    @echo off
    FOR %%a IN (%*) DO echo [%%~a]
```

**Java** (surrounding quotes automatically removed)

```
    public class TestArg {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (String a : args) {
                System.out.println("[" + a + "]");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, if you do want to go nonstandard, you COULD have your BAT or other program just loop through all args, and concatenate all that do NOT start with a "-" with a space to the previous one. This however is more complicated. It will also get values with more than one space wrong as there is no way for the operation system (command line) to know that there where more spaces. Rather go with quotes.

Comment: Hi, Friedwin. I have tried this. CMD will prompt a warning:   g2"" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Hi @Xxg, please have a look again at what you have typed. It seems you have typed two quotes **after** the argument. You should type one at the start and one at the end of the arg value (copy an example of your command line if this does not help). Remember that it is the operating system that needs to split up your command line into the command (bat file name) and arguments - it can not tell which spaces separate arguments, and which spaces are part of the argument value, unless you surround the argument that contains spaces with quotes (e.g. `"arg with spaces"`).

Comment: Hi Friedwin, thanks for your help, I found that the code of my 'bat' file are not correct, I have fixed it. You are absolutely right.

Comment: just a quick tip, to get it back without quotes, you can use "set arg1=%~1".

Comment: *‘…as the quotes will just be ignored’* – **No, they won't.** A simple reference to an argument *preserves* the surrounding quotes if they are present. If you want to "ignore" the quotes around the `"-ar g2"`, you'll need to reference the argument like @ProfPickle has suggested, i.e. as `%~2` instead of just `%2`.

Comment: You're right @Andriy M & Prof Pickle, my confusion. I was thinking of other programs called from the command line, batch files work differently. Editing post above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it possible to split the string with | character, and then trim the values (left + right) ? This should preserve the spaces inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below... just proof of concept code, the rest you'll need to do yourself... or buy a book on java programming like I did.

```
public static void main(String argv[])
    {
    String argument1 = "";
    String argument2 = "";
    String argument2value = "";
    String argument3 = "";
    for(int c=0;c<argv.length;c++)
        {
        if(argv[c].indexOf("-")==0)
            {
            if(argument1.length() == 0)
                {
                argument1 = argv[c].substring(1,argv[c].length());
                }
            if(argument2.length() == 0)
                {
                argument2 = argv[c].substring(1,argv[c].length());
                }  
            }
        else
            {
            if(argument2.length() != 0)
                {
                argument2value = argument2value + argv[c]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you could check the check next to my answer then ;-)